# Cant display Result from api fetch into a variable to be displayed elsewhere

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, console.log

I have received back from my api the data, which would just be a letter, which is a rating, But when trying to store it into a variable to be used elsewhere or return it, it comes back with undefined and was wondering if there was any solution in order to get this as a variable so I can display it elsewhere? The url has been changed to the variable URL for privacy purposes

propertydetails.js

```
import './Styling.css';
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav.js';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Resultbar from './Resultbar';

import { MyContext } from '../MyContext';

var costs_icon = require ('./CostsIcon.png');
var low_energy_lighting_icon = require ('./LowEnergyIcon.png');
var glazing_icon = require ('./GlazingIcon.png');
var co2_icon = require('./CO2.png');

export default function  PropertyDetails() {
  const {state, setState}=useContext(MyContext);

  
  function PostRequest(co2emissions,lightingvalue,heatingvalue,watervalue,multiglazevalue,amount,selects,rooms,heatedrooms,lowlightingvalue){
    const payload={"data":[[1,co2emissions,lightingvalue,heatingvalue,watervalue,multiglazevalue,amount,selects,rooms,heatedrooms,lowlightingvalue]]}
    fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      mode:'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      
      console.log('Success:', data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
    
}

function Post_Handler()
    { 
              
        PostRequest(state.co2emissions,state.lightingvalue,state.heatingvalue,state.watervalue,state.multiglazevalue,state.amount,state.selects,state.rooms,state.heatedrooms,state.lowlightingvalue);
      };



    return (
      <body>
        <div class ="heading">3. Enter Property Details</div>
        <div class= "container">
                  <Nav/>
          <div class = "center">
            <div class = "greybox">
                <div class = "costs"><img src={costs_icon}/></div>
                <div class = "coststexts">Costs</div>
                <div class = "lowenergylighting"><img src={low_energy_lighting_icon}/></div>
                <div class = "lowenergytexts">Low Energy Lighting</div>
                <div class = "glazing"><img src = {glazing_icon}/></div>
                <div class = "glazingtext">Glazing</div>
                <div class = "co2icon"><img src = {co2_icon}/></div>
                <div class = "co2text">CO2</div>
              
               
                <div class = "heatingcost"><input type ="text" placeholder='£'onChange={(event) => {setState(prev=>({...prev,'heatingvalue':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>
                <div class = "lightingcost"><input type ="text" placeholder='£' onChange={(event) => {setState(prev=>({...prev,'lightingvalue':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>
                <div class = "watercost"><input type ="text" placeholder='£' onChange={(event) =>  {setState(prev=>({...prev,'watervalue':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>
                <div class = "heatingcosttext">Heating</div>
                <div class = "lightingcosttext">Lighting</div>
                <div class = "watercosttext">Water</div>
                <div class = "multiglaze"><input type ="text" placeholder='%' onChange={(event) =>  {setState(prev=>({...prev,'multiglazevalue':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>
                <div class = "multiglazetext">Multiglaze</div>
                <div class = "percentage"><input type ="text" placeholder='%' onChange={(event) =>  {setState(prev=>({...prev,'lowlightingvalue':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>
                <div class = "co2"><input type = "text" placeholder= 'tonnes'onChange={(event) =>  {setState(prev=>({...prev,'co2emissions':parseInt(event.target.value)}))}}/></div>

                <div>heating is:{state.heatingvalue}</div>
                <div> lighting is: {state.lightingvalue}</div>
                <div> water is: {state.watervalue}</div>
                <div> multiglaze is: {state.multiglazevalue}</div>
                <div> low energy lighting is: {state.lowlightingvalue}</div>
                <div> CO2 is: {state.co2emissions}</div>
           


                
              
             <Resultbar />


            </div>

          <Link to = "/Energy">
           <div class = "backbutton"><button>BACK</button></div>
          </Link>
          <div className='Result'><button onClick={Post_Handler}>GET RESULT</button></div>
          </div>
          
  
          
        </div>
  
      </body>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the use case for useState.

add

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState();
```

then change

```
// return data
setRating(data);
```

and use it like

```
<div>{rating}</div>
```

Comment: How would this allow for the data to be stored in a variable from the api fetch ?

Comment: I believe the payload from the fetch API is an object 'data'. Can you log it to the console?

Comment: yes so the data gets logged in the console correctly, but I can store it anywhere else in order to access it to be displayed within the webpage

Comment: Calling `setRating("B")` will cause the variable `rating` to become `"B"`. it's all here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html